# how to create a post request using fast api and sqlalchemy while working with a foreign key constraint

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, python-3.x, fastapi

This is my first time using `FastApi` the python framework and i am trying to understand how to correctly setup my tables and logic to be able to make a post request that create an instance of the table that has the foreign key

## models.py

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
```

## schemas.py

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    name: str

class Posts(BaseModel):
    id: int
    user_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class User(UserBase):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

## repository.py

```
def create_post(db: Session, user_id: int, post: schemas.Post):
    get_user_id = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()
    
    post = models.Post(
        id=post.id,
        user_id=get_user_id.id,
    )

    db.add(post)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(post)
    return post
```

## endpoint

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/posts.", response_model=Post)
async def create_post(user_id, post: Post, db):
    return repository.create_post(db=db, user_id=user_id, post=post)
```

## front end

```
try {
       const url = "http://localhost:8000/posts";
       const data = {"user_id": 2};


       const response = await fetch(url, {
           method: "POST",
           headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
...
```

The `user_id` tried above in the front end exist in the database and the endpoint to create a user work fine but just the one to create a `post` that belong to a specific user do not work return a `422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Is there something that i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your endpoint currently requires 2 things: a `user_id` and data from a `Post` schema. (It also asks for `db` which I don't know how you manage your access to your db) (`create_post(user_id, post: Post, db)`)

So your body must contain the values of Post, namely: `id` and `user_id`. At this point, we realize that you ask twice in your endpoint `user_id` . You can therefore delete your first `user_id` from your endpoint since it is included in your `Post` schema.

On the front-end, your `data` contains only one data: `{"user_id": 2}`. It is missing the value for `id` which is requested via your `Post` schema. So, since there is one piece of data missing, a 422 error is raised.